# How to use variables in Teradata SQL Macros

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, macros, teradata

I'm wanting to use variables inside my macro SQL on Teradata.

I thought I could do something like the following:

```
REPLACE MACRO DbName.MyMacro  
(  
   MacroNm   VARCHAR(50)  
)  
AS  
(  

   /* Variable to store last time the macro was run */  

   DECLARE V_LAST_RUN_DATE TIMESTAMP;  


   /* Get last run date and store in V_LAST_RUN_DATE */  

   SELECT LastDate  
   INTO V_LAST_RUN_DATE  
   FROM DbName.RunLog  
   WHERE MacroNm = :MacroNm;  


   /* Update the last run date to now and save the old date in history */  

   EXECUTE MACRO DbName.RunLogUpdater(  
      :MacroNm  
     ,V_LAST_RUN_DATE  
     ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
   );  

);
```

However, that didn't work, so I thought of this instead:

```
REPLACE MACRO DbName.MyMacro  
(  
   MacroNm   VARCHAR(50)  
)  
AS  
(  

   /* Variable to store last time the macro was run */  

   CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MacroVars AS  
   (  
         SELECT  LastDate AS V_LAST_RUN_DATE  
           FROM  DbName.RunLog  
          WHERE  MacroNm = :MacroNm;  
   )  
   WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;  


   /* Update the last run date to now and save the old date in history */  

   EXECUTE MACRO DbName.RunLogUpdater(  
      :MacroNm  
     ,SELECT V_LAST_RUN_DATE FROM MacroVars  
     ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
   );  

);
```

I can do what I'm looking for with a Stored Procedure, however I want to avoid for performance.

Do you have any ideas about this?
Is there anything else I can try?

Cheers
Tim

Comment: Out of curiosity, what performance problems is your stored proc causing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't DECLARE a variable inside of a macro. What you are trying to accomplish could be handled with an UPDATE statement if you so choose.

```
UPDATE TGT
FROM <dbname>.<target table> TGT
   , (SELECT MacroName
           , LastRunDate
      FROM <dname>.<source table>
     ) SRC
SET LastRunDate = SRC.LastRunDate
  , EffectiveTimestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
WHERE TGT.MacroName = SRC.MacroName
;
```